# Showing a Dialog in Tooltip - Material UI, react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I am new to Material UI. So I tried to change an existing code and encountered this issue. I want to change a  view to .

This is the existing code

```
<TableCell>
    <Button  >
      <InfoRounded style={{ color: "teal" }} onMouseOver={handleClickOpen}/>
    </Button>
    <SimpleDialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} />
  </TableCell>
```

This coding is similar to the example in Material UI.
[Material UI coding sample link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ps9nf?file=/demo.js)

This is what I have tried until now

```
<TableCell>
    <Tooltip title ="I need to get the Dialog view here" InfoRounded>
      <Button sx={{m:1}}>
        <InfoRounded style={{color:"teal"}}/>
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>
  </TableCell>
```

I need to get the dialog kind of view in this tool tip. Can anyone help me with this? I tried more than a day and still couldn't figure it out.

While I hover the button the dialog card need to show and when I mover the mouse point it need to close the dialog box automatically. (Currently with the first code the dialog box will open when I hover the button, but to close it I need to click the screen)

Comment: You can put some HTML/JSX in the title prop of the [tooltip](https://mui.com/api/tooltip/). I updated the material UI [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/simpledialog-material-demo-forked-b4l2h?file=/demo.js) to show the content in the tooltip.